# Loading shared libraries (.so) distributed by --files argument with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, java-native-interface, native

I'm trying to work with an external native library (.so file) when running a spark job. First of all I'm submitting the file using `--files` argument.

To load the library I'm using `System.load(SparkFiles.get(libname))` after creating the `SparkContext` (to make sure `SparkFiles` are populated).
Problem is that the library is only loaded by the driver node, and when tasks try to access the native methods I'm getting

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, 13.0.0.206, executor 0): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

The only thing that worked for me was copying the `.so` file to all the workers before running the spark app, and creating a Scala object that would load the library before each task (can be optimized with `mapPartitions`).

I tried using

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/local/path/to/so" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/local/path/to/so"
```

to try to avoid that, but without success.

Now since I'm using EMR to run spark jobs, and not a consistent cluster,
I would like to avoid copying files to all the nodes before running the job.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which mode you are using client mode or clustermode for spark submit?

Comment: I'm using cluster mode

Comment: SparkContext has `void addFile(String path)` Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark
job on every node. have you tried this?

Comment: also these kind of initialization `mappartitions` (per partition) is better/efficient than `map` (every element)

Comment: mappartitions was already discussed in the post as a possible optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was simpler than I thought - All I need is for the library to be loaded once per JVM

so basically what I need is to add the library file using `--files` and to create a Loader object:

```
object LibraryLoader {
    lazy val load = System.load(SparkFiles.get("libname"))
}
```

and use it before each task (`map`, `filter` etc.)

for example

```
rdd.map { x =>
    LibraryLoader.load
    // do some stuff with x
}
```

the laziness will ensure object will be created after SparkFiles are populated, and also single evaluation per JVM.

Comment: I was trying to apply your own solution in my project. I am using DataFrame/UDFs and a UDF is calling a native function that is defined in a SO file. How can load these libraries without using a map method?

Comment: @Vitrion, I would load it directly from the UDF definition.

Comment: In `System.load(SparkFiles.get("libname"))`, should you reference the library w/ the ".so" extension and should you prepend w/ the path to it?