# How to reference .so files in spark-submit command

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, timesten

I am using **TimesTen** Database with **Spark 2.3.0**

I need to refer to .so files in spark-submit command in order to connect to Timesten db.

Is there any option for same in `spark-submit`?

I tried adding so file in `--conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath` still it doesn't resolve the error.

**Error** I am getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 135 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 135.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 5308, 10.180.25.241, executor 3): java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbcCS in java.library.path
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.connect(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1809)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:305)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.saveTable(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
        at com.sample.Transformation.main(Transformation.java:195)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Problems with loading native library/missing methods: no ttJdbcCS in java.library.path
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.connect(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1809)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:305)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:821)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**My spark-submit command**

```
./spark-submit \
--class com.sample.Transformation \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5001 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=11264 \
--conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/scratch/rmbbuild/Timesten/TimesTen/tt1122/lib \
--executor-memory=91GB \
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=11264 \
--driver-memory=91G \
--executor-cores=17  \
--driver-cores=17 \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=306 \
--jars /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-api-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/drools-compiler-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-maven-support-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-internal-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/xstream-1.4.10.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-commons-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/ecj-4.4.2.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/mvel2-2.4.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-project-datamodel-commons-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-project-datamodel-api-7.7.0.Final.jar,/scratch/rmbbuild/Timesten/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/ttjdbc8.jar --driver-class-path /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar:/scratch/rmbbuild/Timesten/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/ttjdbc8.jar  \
--master spark://10.180.181.189:7077 \
"/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/POC-jar/Transformation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" \
> /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/POC-jar/logs/logstt21.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spark.executor.extraLibraryPath` is a path used on the executors, as the name suggests, so your `.so` must be available at that location on all of the executors.

Either it must be installed at your specified absolute path on all executor nodes (i.e. at `/scratch/rmbbuild/Timesten/TimesTen/tt1122/lib`), or it can be uploaded to the executors using the `--files` option of `spark-submit`, where it will be available to your job in the working directory of the executor.

See also this question:

- [Loading shared libraries (.so) distributed by --files argument with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741082/loading-shared-libraries-so-distributed-by-files-argument-with-spark)

Comment: so you mean I give the option like --files /scratch/rmbbuild/Timesten/TimesTen/tt1122/lib ?

Comment: will it require Java coding as well? As shown in the reference question in scala?

Comment: I'd assume that the client libraries you are using will try to load the .so file, so you wouldn't need to do this in your own code - but I'm not familiar with the TimesTen database.

Comment: Just realized - you are running in standalone mode aren't you (not YARN)? I'm not sure the `--files` option will work for standalone, though not 100% certain as I always use YARN.

Comment: no i am using cluster mode and  i kept my libraries on all executors and using extraLibraryPath

Comment: It worked when i deployed libs on all executors.. Thanks :)